# The circle wont render without it being distorted, how to make it smooth after render. Help

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

Every time i render the artwork it creates a strange surface instead of the smooth texture i can see on the edit screen. 
[image]

any ideas why and how to fix this?
I have a feeling its the object but could possibly be something to do with the settings I have set for the materials.

I am sort of new the 3d modelling...

I have tried to insert a replacement circle into the position but do not know how to scale and rotate to the same axis as the original.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok...kicking myself after noticing the layers which are turned off in the layers panel still show up in the final render..

so... lesson learned... **DELETE** the layers you do not use as they will cause a problem.

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because it is wrong. Just disable the rendering of the collection in the [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#outliner).

Comment: Thank you for your help, finding some of these settings can be troublesome to find. Sorry if my answer wasn't accurate.

Comment: Don't worry, that is part of the workings of stackexchange. You can always edit your answer to add or change information. I have added another answer, in case future users discover this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden objects have restricted [visibility](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/visibility.html) in the [viewport](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/introduction.html#introduction). But hiding them with <kbd>H</kbd> for example, won't restrict them from beeing rendered. If you want objects or collections to not show up in your render ("*render looks different from viewport*") then you have to restrict their renderability as well, by clicking the camera icon in the [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#outliner).

[image: hidden objects]

See the visibility notes of the [collections page.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#collections)